# npm module dependency graph not similar

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-managers

I am using `npm-remote-ls` package to list the dependency tree for a module. It is installed globally in my system.

Command 1 : `npm-remote-ls object-assign`

Lists the following tree -

[image]

Command 2 : `npm-remote-ls forever`

Lists the following tree -

[image]

From the graph 1, it can be seen that there are certain dependencies of module `object-assign`, but in graph 2 the tree terminates at that point itself and shows no further dependencies.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

`mocha` is a dev dependency of `object-assign@3.0.0` [see](https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign/blob/3.0.0/package.json#L36)

`npm-remote-ls` only show dev dependencies from requested package, not for transitive dependencies.

The comment from [npm-remote-ls/lib/remote-ls.js](https://github.com/npm/npm-remote-ls/blob/bc233b6e15364c3868362030d5b00aa43cc48696/lib/remote-ls.js#L70):62-88 says it all.

```
RemoteLS.prototype._walkDependencies = function (task, packageJson, done) {
  var _this = this
  var version = this._guessVersion(task.version, packageJson)
  var dependencies = _.extend(
    {},
    packageJson.versions[version].dependencies,
    this.optional ? packageJson.versions[version].optionalDependencies : {},
    this.peer ? packageJson.versions[version].peerDependencies : {},
    // show development dependencies if we're at the root, and deevelopment flag is true.
    (task.parent === this.tree && this.development) ? 
    packageJson.versions[version].devDependencies : {}
  )

...
}
```